# How to properly add "Valid redirect URIs" in keycloack and redirect to external domain after Authenthification in default account client frontend?

Tags: keycloak

After giving https://dbister.com/* as "Valid redirect URIs" in default account client frontend
[image]    http://127.0.0.1:8001/realms/test/account/ , im getting " We are sorry...
Invalid redirect uri"
when i check the logs redirect_uri its not changed, and dosent work
2023-06-13 11:46:02,224 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-5) type=LOGOUT_ERROR, realmId=daa23297-7dc5-43fb-abaa-13d06a68fb3b, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.18.0.1, error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8001/realms/test/account/#/

I tryed onl change this "Valid redirect URIs" , but Im thinking that my configuration and perception is wrong, or that we cant simply use redirect to external domain, so far did find any examples on whole internet

Answer (score 0):

Why are you redirecting your account client to dbister?
Anyway, you can achieve it using this:

Remove Root URL: this will add your url root to the Valid redirect URL.
Also, you need to check the account-console client as they have the same configuration.

[image]

I suggest you need to create a new client and not use the account and account-console clients.

Comment: leaving root url and homer url blank, and just redirect it should work so far, thanks

Comment: yes, that should be fine but the main solution would just be removing the root url. and create a new client for this. thank you